# Identifying HTTP_REFERER screen resolution of window outside div overlay

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form which is overlayed over the visitors current page using jQuery when the user clicks on a div in the bottom right of a web page.  This overlay pulls up an iframe but I need to record the page the visitor clicked from to get to the overlay (essentially the HTTP_REFERER) along with the resolution of the window the user clicked from.

As of now I am attempting to grab this information after the form has been passed, my concern is that the information I will be provided with will not not be correct and will instead give me the window size of the overlay and since it's a separate iframe won't be able to grab the HTTP_REFERER.  Are these assumptions correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you create a hidden field in the form?

If so you could then update this hidden field with the url of the page the user came from.

```
var current_url = window.location.pathname;

$('#myHiddenField').val(current_url);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parent window res with js: parent.document.body.clientHeight/Width